# Azure AD B2C REST API : Create Bulk Local Accounts

Tags: azure, rest, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to create users in bulk via the REST API. Same as we do for single user in the below URL.

> https://graph.windows.net/{MYADB2C}.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6

We have the provision via the Azure portal but could'nt find anything with REST API.

**UPDATED**
Sample request for Batch processing

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/{}.onmicrosoft.com/$batch?api-version=1.6
Headers :
Authorization : {token}
Content-Type : multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_***********

Body :
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/users",
      "body": {
        "accountEnabled": true,
        "creationType": "LocalAccount",
        "displayName": "test1@gamil.com",
        "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration, DisableStrongPassword",
        "passwordProfile": {
          "password": "***",
          "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
        },
        "signInNames": [
          {
            "type": "emailAddress",
            "value": "test1@gamil.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/users",
      "body": {
        "accountEnabled": true,
        "creationType": "LocalAccount",
        "displayName": "test2@gmail.com",
        "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration, DisableStrongPassword",
        "passwordProfile": {
          "password": "***",
          "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
        },
        "signInNames": [
          {
            "type": "emailAddress",
            "value": "test1@gamil.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can batch operations by referring to [Batch processing | Graph API concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing#additional-resources-).

But we recommend you use [Microsoft Graph API JSON Batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) instead of Azure AD Graph Batch processing because Azure AD Graph content is no longer updated.

An example using Microsoft Graph API here:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/users",
      "body": {
          "accountEnabled": true,
          "displayName": "at1",
          "mailNickname": "at1",
          "userPrincipalName": "at1@**.onmicrosoft.com",
          "passwordProfile" : {
              "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
              "password": "password-value"
          }
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/users",
      "body": {
          "accountEnabled": true,
          "displayName": "at2",
          "mailNickname": "at2",
          "userPrincipalName": "at2@**.onmicrosoft.com",
          "passwordProfile" : {
              "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
              "password": "password-value"
          }
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "/users",
      "body": {
          "accountEnabled": true,
          "displayName": "at3",
          "mailNickname": "at3",
          "userPrincipalName": "at3@**.onmicrosoft.com",
          "passwordProfile" : {
              "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
              "password": "password-value"
          }
      },
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can have a quick test in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Comment: Thanks Allen, but i am using Azure AD Graph API the references that you have given works for Microsoft Graph API only.

Comment: @coder89 Yes. As I mentioned in answer, Azure AD Graph is not recommended. If you insist, please refer to the first document I provided: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing. This is Azure AD Graph Batch processing.

Comment: Understood but when I use the Azure AD Graph API for Batch process I don't get any response back it simply returns 202 Accepted ! So that why I was wondersing if there is any other ref that i can check for  the same.

Comment: @coder89 Are the users created successfully in B2C tenant? Can you show your request details?

Comment: No the user is not getting created in AD B2C. I have updated my question with sample batch request.

Comment: @coder89 You are putting wrong request body for the request. What you have provided is for Microsoft Graph rather than AAD Graph. Please note that you should provide `multipart/mixed` Content-Type body which is like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing#sample-request. You can have a test with this code sample: https://github.com/CrazyTuna/azure-active-directory-batchprocessing.